# range function seems to ignore comparison operators

Tags: python

New programmer here ...
python range function seems to ignore comparison operators.

For example, if I have the following function:

```
def test(x):
    for i in range(0,6):
        if i < x:
            print i
```

If I execute test(3), my understanding is that the function should stop after printing out 0,1,2,3. However, it print 0-5.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Can you show the code running in the repl (command line) and the result? I wonder if you are passing the string `"3"` to your function rather than the integer `3`?

Comment: I don't believe you. It outputs `0,1,2` as expected.

Comment: Also, I would expect it to print 0, 1 and 2. I wouldn't expect it to print 3 since 3 is not less than 3.

Comment: Try changing your code to `if i < int(x):` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on you passing the string `"3"` to your function, rather than the integer `3`. Where does your 3 come from? Is it from `raw_input` by any chance?

Due to historical reasons, python 2 considers all integers to be "less than" all strings, as for these different types it falls back to comparing their type names and `"int" < "str"`.